# Can I put Wildcard Security Seal in both primary domain and sub domains

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to add Wildcard Security Seal in our websites.

I already add the Seal on primary domain (https://www.mydomain.com.sg) and it is displayed properly.

When I tried to add that Seal on sub domain (https://www.subdomain1.mydomain.com.sg), the Seal on primary domain is disappeared. When I tried to delete that Seal on sub domain, the Seal on primary domain is displayed correctly.

I also need to add that Seal on another sub domains.

I would like to know that can I use Wildcard Security Seal in both Primary domain and sub domains?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As response from Godaddy Support Team, Wildcard Security can protect all sub domains and also can use SSL seal in both primary domain and sub domains.

Now, I added the SEAL on primary and sub domains. It is displayed properly. 
After added the SEAL, it needs to restart the website as optional.